# Django admin change history log

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Django admin includes a "History" page, which shows the modification history for a given model.

In different models, the changed field is shown either as an "Act" or  as a "Comment": [image]

Is it possible to change a "Comment" to an "Act"? Because I'm currently unable to properly display changes to the model since "comments" follow a different messaging format.

We are not using any external packages like simple-history, etc. This is the default Django logging.

We couldn't find any information about overwriting history in Django admin. I couldn't find nowhere specified "comment" or "action" specified anywhere in the source code neither.

Comment: I just wrote the almost same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74487494/translate-django-admin-log-entry-messages did you ever find solution ?