# Translate django admin log entry messages

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I've a small django mezzanine application in https://github.com/miettinj/mezzanine It translates admin interface correctly, but it also should translate the page history to understandable form. (I guess it comes directly from django_admin_log in database)

Now the admin log looks like this:

```
{
  "model": "admin.logentry",
  "pk": 2,
  "fields": {
    "action_time": "2022-11-18T08:34:03.136Z",
    "user": 1,
    "content_type": 18,
    "object_id": "1",
    "object_repr": "janes post",
    "action_flag": 2,
    "change_message": "[{\"changed\": {\"fields\": [\"Content\", \"Keywords\"]}}]"
  }
}
```

How can I change it so that it translates the action 'changed', remains the field names unchanged and totally removes the unuserfrienly characters: `("[{\)` ?

In the attachment the lines surrounded with blue are correct and lines surrounded with read are current functionality.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might be coming late to the game but I had the same question recently.

First of all, you first show a json (**which is also a dict in python**) which can easily be parsed in python:

> ```
> {
>   "model": "admin.logentry",
>   "pk": 2,
>   "fields": {
>     "action_time": "2022-11-18T08:34:03.136Z",
>     "user": 1,
>     "content_type": 18,
>     "object_id": "1",
>     "object_repr": "janes post",
>     "action_flag": 2,
>     "change_message": "[{\"changed\": {\"fields\": [\"Content\", \"Keywords\"]}}]"
>   }
> }
> ```

This can be parsed in python to keep only the "change_message" field either by considering it as json representation (JSON double parsing) or a dictionary representation:

### Dict:

```
    data = {
  "model": "admin.logentry",
  "pk": 2,
  "fields": {
    "action_time": "2022-11-18T08:34:03.136Z",
    "user": 1,
    "content_type": 18,
    "object_id": "1",
    "object_repr": "janes post",
    "action_flag": 2,
    "change_message": "[{\"changed\": {\"fields\": [\"Content\", \"Keywords\"]}}]"
  }
}

change_message = data['fields']['change_message']

print(change_message)
```

With the output being: *[{"changed": {"fields": ["Content", "Keywords"]}}]*

---

### JSON

```
import json

# Your JSON string
json_str = """
{
  "model": "admin.logentry",
  "pk": 2,
  "fields": {
    "action_time": "2022-11-18T08:34:03.136Z",
    "user": 1,
    "content_type": 18,
    "object_id": "1",
    "object_repr": "janes post",
    "action_flag": 2,
    "change_message": "[{\\"changed\\": {\\"fields\\": [\\"Content\\", \\"Keywords\\"]}}]"
  }
}
"""

# Parse the JSON string into a Python object
data = json.loads(json_str)

# Extract the 'change_message' field
change_message = data['fields']['change_message']

print(change_message)
```

With the output being *[{"changed": {"fields": ["Content", "Keywords"]}}]*

---

## Final Parsing

Now, either you take the whole JSON file and then you parse it to take the "change_message" or you take directly the "change_message" from the LogEntry, then you will need to further parse it and define the display that you want. You can do for example:

```
import json

# Your JSON string
json_str = "[{\"changed\": {\"fields\": [\"Content\", \"Keywords\"]}}]"

# Parse the JSON string into a Python object
parsed = json.loads(json_str)

# Extract 'fields' from 'changed' and join with a comma
fields = ', '.join(parsed[0]['changed']['fields'])

output = f"Changed: {fields}"

print(output)
```

With the output being: ***Changed: Content, Keywords***